Realizing arithmetic hierarchy in algebraic number theory
Is it possible to realize arithmetic hierarchy in algebraic number theory?
For example, consider a $\Pi^0_4$ statement of the form $\forall x \exists y \forall z \exists w \phi(x,y,z,w)=0$ where $\phi$ is some recursive function and $x,y,z,w$ are elements of an algebraic number field. Are there such statements in algebraic number theory?
Related posts:
logics restricted in arithmetic hierarchy

Having $\phi$ be a recursive function (i.e. computable function) is rather like having another existential quantifier, to say that it converges, and so it may be more natural/clear to strip that out and say that $\phi$ is primitive recursive, since the extra existential quantifer can be absorbed into $\exists w$.
